# How to configure corporate HTTP proxy with authentication

Tags: docusignapi

I am testing the DocuSign API Client for Java.

The problem is that the testing environment as well as the production environment is behind a corporate Proxy that needs authentication (username + password, not just host + port).

But I see no way to configure the DocuSign ApiClient.

I only can set up `http.proxyHost` and `http.proxyPort`, but no `http.proxyUser` and `http.proxyPassword`.

```
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyHost", host);
System.getProperties().put("https.proxyHost", host);
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPort", String.valueOf(port));
System.getProperties().put("https.proxyPort", String.valueOf(port));
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyUser", user);
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPassword", password);
Authenticator.setDefault(
   new Authenticator() {
      @Override
        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            if (getRequestorType() == Authenticator.RequestorType.PROXY) {
                System.out.println(getRequestingHost() + ":" + getRequestingPort() + " -> " + getRequestingURL());
                return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password.toCharArray());
            }
            return null;
        }
   }
);
```

Setting the `Authenticator.setDefault()` works with default java http client, but it does not show any effect when using the DocuSign ApiClient.

Comment: Try calling DS API from your own code (without SDK) just to be sure if you have correct proxy details. Write code using `com.sun.jersey.client.*.*` library and if it works with your proxy then we can check why DS SDK is not working.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can do that using:

For HTTPS (recommended): https.proxyHost, https.proxyPort, https.proxyUser and https.proxyPassword

For HTTP: http.proxyHost, http.proxyPort, http.proxyUser and http.proxyPassword

this was added in version 2.9.0 of the client which was released in Feb, so if you have that or later - you should be good

Answer (score 0):

I have updated from 2.8.0 to 2.9.0.

I have tested it but currently I still get the same exception `com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.0 407 Proxy Authentication Required"`

I used this code as recommended in the last answer:

```
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyHost", host);
System.getProperties().put("https.proxyHost", host);
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPort", String.valueOf(port));
System.getProperties().put("https.proxyPort", String.valueOf(port));
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyUser", user);
System.getProperties().put("https.proxyUser", user);
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPassword", password);
System.getProperties().put("https.proxyPassword", password);
```

The problem is that `http.proxyUser` and `http.proxyPassword` don't get recognized by the DocuSign API Client.